# Is there any work around to use generatedMasterViews directly from data management api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Lately I've been using BIM360Team to store all of my team's .rvt files and then I want to use the room data from the model itself to manipulate some information.

The main goal of using .rvt instead of .nwc for room data extraction is to reduce the re-work as much as possible, So I found this update https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces which I really grateful for this update. But it required to translate model again rather than using data management api to get the svf from BIM360Team directly

So is it possible to extract the model data likely using the model derivative api new features? your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thank you for the interest on the new feature of translation. Are you looking for the possibility to extract room data from the translated SVF data of BIM 360 Team?  Firstly, room is one more metadata of translation, instead of SVF stores the room data. And if without generateMasterView param, room data will not be extracted. So you will have to perform a new translation with generateMasterView param. It is not feasible to get out such info with previous metadata. Sorry if this is not convenient to you. If I misunderstood your question, please elaborate to help me to get to know better.

Comment: Thank you for your kind responses. The answer is completely clear. Now I perform new translation as you mention and it's working fine. I hope that in the future update you may consider adding some option to data management api to get the SVF from BIM360Platform that working like re-translation with generateMasterView option. :)